# SQL Server XML Joining using Exist() for Performance

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm trying to improve a query that's taking a bit of time (possibly looking in the wrong spot, but I know XML is a good place to start, so that's what I'm going with for now).

The XML looks like this;

```xml
<BlockModels>
    <BlockModel id="1"></BlockModel>
</BlockModels>
```

Pretty simple and unfortunately outside of my control. It is a fixed format/definition.

The SQL statement looks like this:

```sql
SELECT bm.Name, b.BlockModel.value('(./@id)[1]', 'INT')
FROM @iBlockModels.nodes('/BlockModels/BlockModel') AS b(BlockMOdel)
INNER JOIN BlockModel AS bm
    ON (bm.Block_Model_Id = b.BlockModel.value('(./@id)[1]', 'INT'))
```

I've followed this documentation; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type, which is where I got the static typing (`[1]`) syntax from. Doesn't seem to have improve performance much though.

In the above documentation, point D mention using `exist()` instead of `value()` but the example doesn't cover joining between two tables. I suspect it's not possible and my attempt at converting the above to something like the example caused it to fail spectacularly. Can anyone assist with the conversion? Or point out anything else I could do to assist with performance?

Comment: It gives you an example of how to do it. In the `sql:column` part you would just put the column name. e.g. `INNER JOIN BlockModel AS bm ON b.BlockModel.exist('.[@id=sql:column("bm.Block_Model_Id")') = 1`

Comment: Ah OK, thanks for the clarification, I was getting confused with the square brackets/root parts. Unfortunately no performance improvement.

Comment: As far as performance, it's probably largely dependent on whether there's an index on your block_model_id column in the blockmodel table (assuming there isn't one - if there is one and you're still having performance issues then I can't see an obvious reason for it based on the query you provided). You're likely to get better performance with the value method of joining as well.

Comment: Yeah, they seem the same, perhaps that's just as good as it gets. Given it only needs the ID(s), maybe I can pull it(them) out to use in an `IN` statement?

Comment: Your original query will probably be much better if you fetch `bm.Block_Model_Id` in the column list instead of getting the value from the XML again.

Answer (score 0):

Shred the id's to a temp table and use that in the join instead.

```sql
create table #bm(ID int primary key);

insert into #bm (ID)
select T.X.value('@id', 'int')
from @iBlockModels.nodes('/BlockModels/BlockModel') as T(X);

select bm.Name, bm.Block_Model_Id
from dbo.BlockModel as bm
  inner join #bm as bm2
    on bm.Block_Model_Id = bm2.id;

drop table #bm;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case it won't make any difference. An `XPath` with `(SomePath)[1]` looks for the first occurance and returns the value. `.exist()` does exactly the same but checks for the existance only. In your case you need the value at `@id`, it would not be enough to check, if this attribute exists... But both calls return with a single value (yes/no or a number) immediately.

The difference is relevant in cases with multiple occurances. If your question is mearly *Is there at least one occurance?* `.exist()` will be faster than `.nodes()` etc.

Your join needs the value of `@id`, so you have to read it over and over. In a `JOIN` this cannot be fast. There are XML indexes, but [I would not recommend to use them](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130969/very-strange-performance-with-an-xml-index)

If performance is very important you might try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tmpTest(ID INT IDENTITY,SomeValue VARCHAR(100),YourXml XML,RefId INT);
GO
```

--create a trigger to write out the needed value on any insert or update

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.InsertUpdate_tmpTest ON tmpTest
FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    WITH UpdateableCTE AS
    (
        SELECT t.RefID AS OldValue
              ,i.YourXml.value(N'/BlockModels[1]/BlockModel[1]/@id',N'int') AS NewValue
        FROM tmpTest AS t
        INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON i.ID=t.ID
    )
    UPDATE UpdateableCTE SET OldValue=NewValue;
END
GO
```

--now you can place an index

```
CREATE INDEX IX_tmpTest_RefId ON tmpTest(RefId);
GO
```

--some behaviour tests

```
INSERT INTO tmpTest(SomeValue,YourXml) VALUES
 ('This is row 1','<BlockModels><BlockModel id="1"></BlockModel></BlockModels>') --ref 1
,('This is row 2','<BlockModels><BlockModel id="1"></BlockModel></BlockModels>') --ref 1
,('This is row 3','<BlockModels><BlockModel id="2"></BlockModel></BlockModels>') --ref 2
,('This is row 4','<BlockModels><BlockModel id="3"></BlockModel></BlockModels>');--ref 3
GO

SELECT * FROM tmpTest;

UPDATE tmpTest SET YourXml='<BlockModels><BlockModel id="99"></BlockModel></BlockModels>' WHERE ID=4;

SELECT * FROM tmpTest;

UPDATE tmpTest SET YourXml='<BlockModels><BlockModel id="0"></BlockModel></BlockModels>' WHERE ID IN(1,2,3);

SELECT * FROM tmpTest;

GO
```

--CleanUp

```
DROP TRIGGER dbo.InsertUpdate_tmpTest;
DROP TABLE tmpTest;
```

This "computed" column `RefId` will be very fast in joins.

About "computed columns": Regrettfully it is - in your case - not possible, to use a computed column (neither *direct* nor *persisted*) together with an index...